# xmlhttprequest is not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have to read xml file placed on ftp server. But when i try to open connection and on php run simple mysql query for checking purpose its not working. Can anybody help please. The code in content script is given.

```
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
alert("connection to ftp server is established successfully");
}
}

var str="name";
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://my severurl/foldername/file.php?     
q="+str,true,"username","password");
xmlhttp.send();
alert("worked");
```

Comment: People here at StackOverflow are really cool, but they **don't have superpowers** ! Give more info ! In what way is it not working (e.g. what is the expected behaviour vs what does actually happen) ? What does your manifest look like ? What other code does your extension have ?

Comment: Thanks StackOverflow people for being cool. Actually response is not working i can send request but cant receive response. In response file i have only receive string named str and echo it. but cant receive response. so being cool and i know for sure you have not super powers

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console log ? Are "username" and "password" actually required ? Do you see any error on server-side, in PHP error log ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you added the permission in the manifest.json:

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://myseverurl/foldername/file.php",
    "tabs",
    "etc..",]
```